# Is there a way to rename s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket which has `demo` in it's name. I want to remove that or give it entirely a new name that is available as a bucket name.

Is there a way to rename the bucket to avoid creating a new bucket and copying all old assets from the old bucket to the new bucket?

Comment: If you're into Ruby: https://gist.github.com/ericskiff/769191 I believe that you have already googled it up and saw that there's no support for renaming. In case you didn't (search) - that's bad that you don't do your research before posting here. And in case you did, since you already know the answer - why did you post the question ? :)

Comment: well, I did googled and answers seems like 2 years old. Just checking if AWS has any more advanced features or not.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=37400
http://reviewofweb.com/amazon/rename-bucket-amazon-s3/